# How do you type a react-navigation navigator with typescript when it can accept params

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to type a React-Navigation (v6) navigator which can accept a param. But I'm facing an issue and I cannot figure out what the problem is.

What I want is to be able to call my navigator `Wizard` with params and without params. This is my need:

```
   navigation.navigate('Wizard');
   navigation.navigate('Wizard', { pageId: 123 });
   navigation.navigate('Wizard', { screen: 'WizardOne' });
```

I have created my types and it looks like this, with the 3 options

```
export type AppNavigatorParamList = {
   // ...
   Wizard:
    | {
        pageId: number;
      }
    | NavigatorScreenParams<WizardNavigatorParamList>
    | undefined;
}

export type WizardNavigatorParamList = {
  WizardOne: undefined;
  WizardTwo: undefined;
};
```

And this is how I try to access the param:

```
  const route = useRoute<RouteProp<AppNavigatorParamList, 'Wizard'>>();
  const pageId = route.params?.pageId;
```

But for some reason, TypeScript keeps complaining about my types. It doesn't find the option where I can just pass the `pageId`.

```
error TS2339: Property 'pageId' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ screen?: undefined; ...
```

These 2 work:

```
   navigation.navigate('Wizard');
   navigation.navigate('Wizard', { screen: 'WizardOne' });
```

But not this one:

```
   navigation.navigate('Wizard', { pageId: 123 });
```

However, if I remove the type `NavigatorScreenParams<WizardNavigatorParamList>` then the one with `pageId` works fine.

What's going on and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if the property exists before accessing it:

```js
if ('pageId' in params) {
  // do something with params.pageId
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the context of accessing it in the `render` method with hooks, as you cannot add conditions before hooks.

Comment: This is the answer to the question you posted. If it's supposed to be used in a hook then you have to handle `undefined` in the hook because your type says that `pageId` won't always be there.